# How to display the JSON data in a table depending on search?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display the data in the table depending on search. How can I achieve this?

```js
var data = [{
    "username": "John Doe",
    "email": "jn@gmail.com",
    "skills": "java,c,html,css"
  },
  {
    "username": "Jane Smith",
    "email": "js@gmail.com",
    "skills": "java,sql"
  },
  {
    "username": "Chuck Berry",
    "email": "cb@gmail.com",
    "skills": "vuejs"
  }
]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="skills">
<input type="email" placeholder="mail id">
<input type="text" placeholder="username">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Expected o/p: 
search any field ex:

```
 input: java,
 output :john and jane profiles
 input:sql
 output: only jane profile //he is the person who has sql skill
 if nothing matches show 0 results
```

User can search using any one field, if any one item matches that profile should be displayed in my table. How can I do this? Can anyone please help me sort it out?

Comment: Simply use DataTables plugin. It's the easiest and most convenient solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
/* Dataset*/
var data = [{
    "username": "John Doe",
    "email": "jn@gmail.com",
    "skills": "java,c,html,css"
},
{
    "username": "Jane Smith",
    "email": "js@gmail.com",
    "skills": "java,sql"
},
{
    "username": "Chuck Berry",
    "email": "cb@gmail.com",
    "skills": "vuejs"
}];



/* Get Result */
function getResult() {
    /* Read value from input fields */
    var skills = $("#skills").val() || '',
        email =  $("#email").val() || '',
        username = $("#username").val() || '';
        
    var result = [],
        i;

    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {        
        if ((skills !== '' && data[i]["skills"].indexOf(skills) !== -1) || (data[i]["email"] === email) ||     (data[i]["username"] === username)) {
            result.push(data[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
};

$('#submit').click(function onClick() {
    console.log(getResult()); // print expected data
});
```

```html
<script 
src= 
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<input id="skills" type="text" placeholder="skills">
<input id="email" type="email" placeholder="mail id">
<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="username"> 
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
```

Comment: How did you call getResult() ?

$('#submit').click(function(){
    var result = getResult(); // you may call like this
    console.log(result);
 });

Comment: yeah Pranab, i tried the same. Don't know what mistake i have done, i'm getting empty object. Can you please edit the snippet, it will help me out

Comment: @Manoj, added the snippet. Please have a look. Hope, this is the thing, you are looking for.

Comment: one more doubt, how to clear the result on click on every search? like if i search java and next if i search for python how to clear the java result and how to display only python? and one more is if i try using uppercase it's not displaying

Comment: you'll get a single result in your case. Here, the snippet is holding the previous result too. To make the result case-insensitive, you'll have to make the condition like below (i showed only for the email, you have to do this for all):
data[i]["email"].toUpperCase() === email.toUpperCase()

Comment: Paranab i have found one issue, when i search for key skill c and username Chuck Berry, it's displaying the data which contains c,like suppose let's take skills and location as input. when i enter c and bangalore it should display only banglore people with skill set of c. In our case it's showing complete data of skill set C

Comment: @Manoj, Please modify the conditions (inside for loop) according to your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

in ES6 you can do it :

```
results = array.filter (x=>x.username.search(search_txt));

let my_list = [{"username":"John Doe","email":"jn@gmail.com","skills":"java,c,html,css"},{"username":"Jane Smith","email":"js@gmail.com","skills":"java,sql"},{"username":"Chuck Berry","email":"cb@gmail.com","skills":"vuejs"}];
results = my_list.filter (x => x.skills.search('java')!=-1);
console.log(results);
//result is : [{"username":"John Doe","email":"jn@gmail.com","skills":"java,c,html,css"},{"username":"Jane Smith","email":"js@gmail.com","skills":"java,sql"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>SEARCH</title>
 </head>
<body>
<input type="text" placeholder="skills" id="skills">
<input type="email" placeholder="mail id" id="email">
<input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username">
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Skills</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="search">

    </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var data = [{
                "username": "John Doe",
                "email": "jn@gmail.com",
                "skills": "java,c,html,css"
              },
              {
                "username": "Jane Smith",
                "email": "js@gmail.com",
                "skills": "java,sql"
              },
              {
                "username": "Chuck Berry",
                "email": "cb@gmail.com",
                "skills": "vuejs"
              }];

    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var skills = $('#skills').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var username = $('#username').val();

        if(username){
            search(username);
        }




    });


    function search(username){
        var name = username;
        var html ;
            data.forEach(function(currentValue, index, array){

                if(currentValue.username == name){
                    html = "<td>"+currentValue.username+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+currentValue.email+"</td"+
                            "<td>"+currentValue.skills+"</td>"
                            ;
                        }else{
                            html = "Result Not Found";
                        }
            });

            return $('#search').html(html);


    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this: it only search by username and showing related data in table

Answer (score 0):

You can make a search function for skills like this:

```js
var data = [{
    "username": "John Doe",
    "email": "jn@gmail.com",
    "skills": "java,c,html,css"
  },
  {
    "username": "Jane Smith",
    "email": "js@gmail.com",
    "skills": "java,sql"
  },
  {
    "username": "Chuck Berry",
    "email": "cb@gmail.com",
    "skills": "vuejs"
  }];
var skills = "java,c";
function search(){
    result = [];
    var setSkills = skills.split(","); console.log(setSkills);
    data.map((current,index)=>{
        let currentSkills = current.skills.split(","); //console.log(currentSkills);
        // currentSkills = ["java", "c", "html", "css"]
        // setSkills = ["java", "c"] ;
        // length of set currentSkills  == length of set (currentSkills + setSkill) --> mean setSkills is subset of currentSkills
        let bool = Array.from(new Set(currentSkills) ).length == Array.from(new Set(currentSkills.concat(setSkills)) ).length;
        if(bool)
            console.log(data[index]);
    });
}
```

```html
        <input type="text" placeholder="skills">
        <input type="email" placeholder="mail id">
        <input type="text" placeholder="username">
        <input type="submit" onclick="search();" value="submit">
```